# PostgreSQL Binary Path in pgAdmin 4 1.0-rc1

Tags: pgadmin-4

What needs to go in the field `PostgreSQL Binary Path` under `File` > `Preferences` > `Path` > `Binary paths`?

Comment: This link should solve your problem http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149169/pgadmin4-postgresql-binary-path-in-the-preferences

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This needs to be a *directory*, not a single file. So on Windows, it's usually `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin`

In future versions of pgAdmin 4 there will be this hint:

`Path to the directory containing the PostgreSQL utility programs (pg_dump, pg_restore etc).`

Answer (score 20):

With the latest version of PostgreSQL 9.6 running on pgAdmin 4, you will find hints under "Help" tab to this two urls after replacing $VERSION$ with the appropriate version number:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.6/pg/ and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ (however, the links don't really give much help as such).

[image]

If you follow the hint below the box and search for "pg_dump, pg_restore" within the directory where you install PostgreSQL, they will be in the "bin" directory/folder

[image]

On windows, with default installations it is something like: **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin**

Copy your path and paste in the boxes under Click on "Binary paths" tab and click on "OK"

[image]

Comment: Mac OS X Sierra the path was /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin

Answer (score 6):

So what you need to do is to configure a path (obviously) :

1. In `pgAdmin` select `File` -> `Preferences` and look for `Path` and then click on `Binary Path` and it needs your path where it says `PostgreSQL Binary Path`
2. Go to your computer -> `C:` (on windows) -> `Program Files` -> `PostgreSQL` -> `your version` -> `bin`. It should be something like this : `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin`. And this is what you need to copy and paste to pgAdmin.
3. Hope it help ☺️

Answer (score 1):

### **2023 Update**

Just add the path of the ***bin*** folder of PostgreSQL. For example:  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin`

[image: For postgre]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the binaries that are related to postgresql should be there. Which is this should be pointed to the 'bin' folder under postgre installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CentOS7 put /usr/bin in binary path, but if does not work:

and... if you are upgrading pgadmin3, uninstall it first and take care of ignore libpq5...

```
sudo yum remove pgadmin3

sudo yum -y install pgadmin4 -x libpq5*

sudo yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

...so maybe it install fine but you need do a backup, maybe you need do some extras steps to configure the Binary Path, so you need do this below:

```
sudo yum install rh-postgresql13-postgresql-syspaths-13.3-1.el7.x86_64
```

if you face a confict error with postgresql96-9.6.23-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 or similar, use it:

```
$ rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

$ sudo yum remove postgresql

$ sudo yum install rh-postgresql13-postgresql-syspaths-13.3-1.el7.x86_64
```

so after it you be able to use `pg_dump

you can check it in terminal

```
$ which psql

$ which pg_dump
```

so now you can configure the Binary Path with /usr/bin and it will work finally...

Answer (score 0):

The default directory for Postgres 14 on windows is:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
[Image of pgAdmin File -> Preferences -> Binary Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz384.png)
I couldn't just cut and paste in the path.  I needed to navigate to the directory.